# Why is the server kernel not install on a server? (10.04.3)

Tags: server, kernel, default

I installed ubuntu-10.04.3-server-amd64.iso

Why is the Desktop Kernel installed?

~# cat /etc/motd
Linux dbxp015 2.6.32-33-generic #70-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 7 21:13:52 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

I know I can install the server kernel

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server

## Why is the server kernel not install on a server?

EDIT: my other machine came up with the proper kernel, there must be somthing wrong with my iso. I dont remeber where I downloaded it from... But i do remeber why i didnt d/l it form ubuntu.com

I cannot wget ubuntu 10.04 server from this page. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download the Direct url for this download link works in the browser, but with wget It gives me 11.10 server.

Tldr this link works in the browser, not from wget.
wget http://www.ubuntu.com/start-download?distro=server&bits=64&release=lts

Comment: You need to update the apt repositories, adn then look for the 3.0 kernel. It may not be available in lucid main, but if it is it'll be there somewhere. Also, to wget images older than the latest release, getting the ISO download links from releases.ubuntu.com helps. http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/ <-- lucid releases and related links

Answer (score 1):

"I cannot wget ubuntu 10.04 server from this page. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download the Direct url for this download link works in the browser, but with wget It gives me 11.10 server".

**If you use the drop down box you can get the 10.04LTS. It shows the 11.10 first**

I just use whatever kernel is in the default repos. Less work that way. There really isn't a reason to use a different kernel unless you are running into problems, or your hardware isn't supported by the kernel you are using.